# Excel VBA error when calling DLL "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: .net, vba, excel, 32bit-64bit

I have an Excel file that calls a .net DLL (called "MyDLL") in the auto_open VBA macro. 
When it gets to the 2nd line below, the error below occurs:

**--VBA Code--**

```
If objSensitivity Is Nothing Then

Set objSensitivity = CreateObject("MyDLL.Calculations") '<<Crashes here
```

**--Error--**

An Error has occured: -2147024885
*Automation error
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

My system is:

- A Windows 7 64-bit PC.
- It has Excel 2003, 2007 and 2010 installed (x86)
- It has .Net Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 installed for both x86 and x64
- It has all the latest windows updates.

Other notes:

- I know that the DLL was created in VS2005 in VB with a Target CPU setting of 'AnyCPU'
- It makes no difference if i change the Target CPU setting of 'X86' - the error still occurs.
- I recently had to rebuild my PC due to a hard drive failure, and before that it worked fine. So i dont know what has happened for it to not work now.
- The issue occurs in all versons of Excel i open the file in.

Since i know that it worked fine previous to my rebuild, and i know it works for other users running it on Windows 7 64 bit, i can only assume it is something else specific to my PC, and not the actual DLL.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted this out.

I did a repair install of all my versions of Office, as i suspected it was a faulty Microsoft Interop DLL OR for some unknown reason, it was using a 64-bit version of the Interop.

Very weird, but its up an running now.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA `CreateObject()` call is used to instantiate COM objects. Has the DLL in question been properly registered to create the appropriate registry entries?

Comment: Yes, i have used regasm.exe to properly register the DLL's. I ran the following in the command prompt: `RegAsm.exe /unregister MyDLL.dll /nologo /silent
RegAsm.exe /tlb:MyDLL.tlb /codebase MyDLL.dll /nologo`

Answer (score 0):

64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit code and vica-versa.  Have you tried *Excel x64*?

Comment: As i mentioned in my initial post, it worked fine before i had to reformat my PC and it works fine for other users of 64-bit OS's?

Comment: I'm not talking about the OS, I'm talking about your 64-bit application trying to access 32-bit Excel.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I thought your DLL accessed Excel, but it's the other way around.  I would have expected compiling the DLL as x86 would have made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the PATH environment variable between your machine and one that works.

It's kind of old fashioned - but the search process for finding dependent DLL files still uses the PATH to find files.

If one of the dependencies of `MyDLL` is somewhere else on the machine (not in the same or a nested directory), a missing `PATH` directory could defeat the loader.